# UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.4 before attempting an upgrade to 3.6;

Tags: mongodb

Kindly assist me on following upgrade issue.

My Arbiter upgrade (thru yum update -y ) has been failed with following error.

```
2019-10-19T07:19:25.944-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-10-19T07:19:25.958-0400 F CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.4 before attempting an upgrade to 3.6; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-upgrade-fcv for more details.
2019-10-19T07:19:25.958-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening so2019-10-19T07:19:25.944-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-10-19T07:19:25.958-0400 F CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.4 before attempting an upgrade to 3.6; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-upgrade-fcv for more details.
2019-10-19T07:19:25.958-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening so
```

Primary and secondary database FCV version was showing 3.4 , where as Arbiter FCV was showing 3.2 in place of 3.4

following error was also there in rs.status()

```
name" : "arbiter1:27017",
   "health" : 0,
   "state" : 8,
   "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",



version status .
replica01 3.4.23 Secondary
replica02 3.4.23 Primary 
replica02  3.4.23 ARBITER
```

Configuration file of three node.

replica01 :

```
storage:
  dbPath: /data
  engine: mmapv1
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
  logAppend: true
processManagement:
  fork: true
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
replication:
  replSetName: productionReplica
 *********************
replica02
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  engine: mmapv1
  journal:
    enabled: true
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
  logAppend: true
processManagement:
  fork: true
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
replication:
  replSetName: productionReplica
net:
  port: 27017
 #bindIp: 127.0.0.1 
*******************************************************
replica03 
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  engine: mmapv1
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
  logAppend: true
processManagement:
  fork: true
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
replication:
  replSetName: productionReplica
```

Please advise how to fix the issue , Seems Arbiter always show FCV one version behind primary database .

Regards
Anurag

Comment: [Arbiters always return the previous version of FCV by design](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-13029). Since arbiters do not replicate data they do not learn the FCV from other members of the replica set and always use the previous FCV version to allow for upgrades/downgrades. If you restart your arbiter with the latest 3.6.x `mongod`, it should work as expected.

Comment: I was getting same error while starting with 3.6 version .